# .NET app connecting to two databases - only one database specified in config file

Tags: .net, sql-server

On one server, I have a .NET application called "MainApp" - one another server, I have two databases called "MainDB_Prod" and "MainDB_Test". I have known for a while that the application connects to the MainDB_Prod database, but I was shocked to learn last week that the application also connects to the MainDB_Test database following a particular click event. I was able to confirm this with some testing at the database level.

I have checked all of the config files in the application folder - I only see connection string information regarding the MainDB_Prod database. Is there some way that the MainDB_Prod database could be making calls to the MainDB_Test database?

Unfortunately, due to poor version control management, I have no way of knowing if I have the most up-to-date source code. However, I do feel that this is likely a database issue. Where can I start to look from here?

Comment: There can be many ways. I would check if there are config transformations in place. The connection string could be hard coded, on another file or even on the database that you know it connects.

Comment: I believe you are checking config files of the deployment server not the local ones. All the data being updated on test db or only a few parts of data go to test and rest go to prod?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya It seems that only a few parts of the data go to test and the rest go to prod.

Comment: One of the possibilities that the connection string is built in a variable @ runtime , a bad habit but i guess you should check it

Comment: You need to check in the code. Somewhere it's hardcoded. You can do find in entire solution for the test db name. Can you identify the pattern of what data goes to which db? Then you can target that particular piece of code to see where itis getting connection syring from.

Comment: @Jake are you aware that .NET assembly can be decompiled and you can look at the source code? There are many tools to do this, you can use for free [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler)

Comment: Coming at this as a DBA, it could be that there's a trigger or some other piece of code in your MainDB_Prod database that reaches into MainDB_Test. How did you confirm the traffic to MainDB_Test? That is, can you say with 100% confidence that the changes are coming from your app and not a "side effect" like I've described above?

Comment: @BenThul I have an event in my app that basically grabs a string from the database and populates a label with that string. I expected that changing that value on the table in the production database would change the value printed in the label. It did not - on a whim, I made a change to that field on the table in the test database and the label then reflected that change.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to disable this on the database side would be to remove access via security for MainDB_Test for the user account trying to gain access if you are worried about those calls.  After that you will need to pull apart the code for the button press, fix it, then recompile and deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Unless define the connection test dB configuration either config level or code level. Check your code please, check your both dB as well as.

For more concrete solution, we all need the details explaination.

Second analysis sql profiler.